# Spring boot service restarts in loop, after adding Mail Server Dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have spring boot micro-services working well.

Recently we wanted to add mail notification feature, so added boot mail starter dependency.
As soon as we did this change, all our services shutdown and start continuously, and below is text on the console log
**Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=...... , current=DOWN, previous=UP]

Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=...... , current=UP, previous=DOWN]**


Also after 4 lines as above there is one more line like 
**Ignoring onDemand update due to rate limiter**


Not sure what could be an issue, but it seems server trying to ping mail server and may be if not getting  pulse trying to shutdown, and next pulse get connection so again making it up.

Has anyone faced such an issue.

Comment: Are those really the only error messages that you get in your service logs? No exceptions, e.g. from the mail server dependency etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after debugging the code, found that some issues when checking health of the mail server, as have actuator used for all services for health check.

Whenever doing health check if there is no response from the mail server, the service goes down. It check for health every 30 seconds. Tried finding parameter to reduce frequency but could not find parameter for it.

So for now did set the management.health.mail.enabled to false, and now service is not shutting down in loop.